# Detecting actual login in Spring Security filter chain

Tags: authentication, spring-security

For a non-trivial setup involving session concurrency control, authentication is not equivalent to login.  For example, a user can be authenticated successfully but still redirected to a logout or error page if this is a second login attempt and `max-sessions="1"`.  If I have post-login logic that needs to be invoked at the point of login (not authentication), what is an optimal way to incorporate this logic into a Spring Security-based webapp?  The solution I came up with, based on my limited understanding of the framework, was to implement my own custom `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` adapter extending the framework's `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` and inject it into `CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy` in my Spring Security configuration XML.  I created a 1-arg constructor and `onAuthentication` method.  `onAuthentication` performs my post-login processing before calling `super.onAuthentication`.  Is there a better way to do this?

My custom `onAuthentication` method looks something like

```
.
.
if (sessionCount < allowedSessions) {
    // Record login timestamp in database
    Date now = new Date();
    userDao.setLastLogin(now);
    userDao.save();
}
super.onAuthentication(...);
```

Because `sessionRegistry` member variable is declared `private` (as opposed to `protected`) in the parent, I had to declare my own `sessionRegistry` and initialize it inside the 1-arg constructor so that my `onAuthentication` method would have access to it.

Comment: What is the logic do you need to perform? Where you would place it will differ depending on what you need access to. For example, if you need access to the HttpServletRequest/Response.

Comment: I need to record a successful login in a database.  So instead of simply returning from `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` when `sessionCount < allowedSessions`, I need to execute logic such as `userDao.setLastLogin(new Date());`.